# Gradle distribution plugin: add files from subprojects in separate folders

Tags: groovy, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I have a multiproject build (projectA) with subprojects projectB and projectC. Each of the subprojects have resources that I would like to add to a zip. The resources for projectB should be in a folder called projectB in the zip.

I am using the distribution plugin to create the zip. This code works, but I would some code that will work regardless of the number and names of subprojects.

```
distributions {
    release {
        baseName 'release'
        contents {
            into('projectB') {
                from 'projectB/src/main/resources/'
            }
            into('projectC') {
                from 'projectC/src/main/resources/'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried the following:

```
distributions {
    release {
        baseName 'release'
        contents {
            subprojects.each {
                p -> into(p.name + '-resources') {
                        from p.projectDir + '/src/main/resources/config'
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but that doesn't compile.

Any suggestions how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sure why, but it works in the following way:

```
apply plugin: 'distribution'

distributions {
  release {
    baseName 'release'
    contents {
      subprojects.each { p ->
        into("${p.name}-resources") {
          from("${p.projectDir}/src/main/resources/config")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Ok, got it. This line was causing problems:

```
from(p.projectDir + "/src/main/resources/config")
```

You can't add `File` to `String`. So both will do the job:

```
from(p.projectDir.toString() + "/src/main/resources/config")
from("${p.projectDir}/src/main/resources/config")
```

Demo can be found [here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/33867965).

Comment: You write that the line is causing problems, but then also writes that both will do the job? Did you mean to change the first line to something else?